# Create Xcode linkable IBActions

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm subclassing different views & controls on iOS, using Xamarin in Xamarin Studio, and I noticed that when I need actions I'm forced to link everything in code.

Creating the outlets and getting them to be recognized in Xcode works. My question is :

**Is there a way to have IBActions recognized in XCode, so I can just link them to my .h the same way I link my outlets ?**

Answer (score 0):

Create the IBAction then add this to your class (if 'test' was the name of your mwethod):

```
    partial void test(NSObject sender)
    {
        Console.Write ("hello");
    }
```